# Microsoft Project 2016 resource calendar seems to be ignored and no overallocation detected

Tags: ms-project, resources, ms-project-2016

yesterday I was trying to put in my resource sheet a part-time worker. I changed his calendar appropriately and then assigned him.

At that point something strange happened.

I summarized everything in this screenshot from an example project I made for the occasion:
[image]

As you can see in the second frame, I changed my calendar to a 8.00 to 12.00 part-time range. 4 hours per day, Monday to Friday.

In the first frame, two ackward things happened:

1. the duration is calculated like if the resource's calendar is a Standard 8 hours per day *(Task 1&3 - 4 hours result in 0,5 days instead of 1; Task 2 - 8 hours result in 1 day instead of 2)*
2. no overallocation is detected between Task 1 and Task 2

What am I missing?

Thank you all for your support,

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the same behaviors as in MSP 2010.

1. Assuming you've created Fixed-Units or Fixed-Work tasks, then the durations of these tasks are 4 hours, 8 hours, and 4 hours - corresponding to the effective work time of the single resource assigned.  The durations are actually stored in minutes, and they are translated to "days" according to the "hours-per-day" Calendar option for the project.  With the default 8-hours/day, your task durations are as expected.  This is normal behavior with assigned resources.
2. The overallocation might be neglected if the Resource Leveling interval is set to Week by Week or Month by Month.  (Check in the Leveling Options on the Resource tab.)